# Swap information on click and hide other's info angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

```
$scope.parentUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
$scope.currentSetUser = false;
        $scope.swapUser = function swapUser(user_id)
        {

            $scope.children.filter(function(item){

                if(item.user_id == user_id)
                {
                    $scope.state = !$scope.state;
                    $scope.currentSetUser = user_id;
                    return $scope.parentUser = item;
                }
            });

        }

 <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">    
                            <uib-accordion-group class="userAssign" ng-repeat="user in children">

                            <span class="main-header-cardion">
                              <a role="button" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="" ng-click="swapUser(user.user_id);" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                              <span ng-if="user.type == '2'">{{user.first_name}}- {{user.user_id}}</span>
                              <span ng-if="user.type == '3'">{{user.name}}- {{user.user_id}}</span>
                            </a>
                            </span>

               <section class="accordion1" ng-show="state">

 <div class="confirm-page-header"> Details of {{parentUser.first_name}} </div>
</section>
 <uib-accordion>
 <uib-accordion-group>
```

Output looks like
John- 112
Jimmy- 113

What I want is ,when I click on John- 112 ,I want to get john's information and hide jimmy's information and when i click on jimmy I want to get jimmy's information and hide john's information

Currently when i click on john it gets me  information for both jimmy and john please guide how to fix this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can we have a working fiddle to understand your problem better ?

Comment: can you pls add more code?